# Messaging directly from web page in Safari like Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

Is there any way to post messages directly from web pages to global page like Chrome's

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage, chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal
```

[API functions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) in Safari?

I've used AngularJS in my web app, and can't think of any clean way integrating it with injected scripts to pass messages to background. My web app is going to initiate some commands to background and get results basically. Currently, trying to convert my Chrome extension to Safari.

Or is there any way my Angular controller speak with injected script if above approach is not possible so that Angular be responsible for updating DOM not injected script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content scripts injected into page are isolated from page's javascript. However they share DOM. Event if you can't call javascript function from content script directly you can use window.postMessage to send some message to content script and listen for message inside CS:

(according to extensions documentation):
contentscript.js

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  // We only accept messages from ourselves
  if (event.source != window)
    return;
  var passedDataObject = event.data;
  //...
  }
}, false);
```

And on the web page:

```
window.postMessage({ /* Object to pass */ }, "*");
```

This is regular message passing on the web sites. postMessage takes two arguments: 1st is a data to pass and second is a target origin (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage for explanations).

Onmessage event have "source" attribute which tells you from which window/frame message come from. In your case you want to listen only for events from page where CS was injected to: `if (event.source != window) return;`

**Edited:**
Documentation for content scripts and message passing you'll find at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: so basically you suggest: web app --window.postMessage--> CS --Safari-API--> global-Page message flow?

Comment: How is this an answer about Safari?

Comment: safari blindness! Sorry, I'm mistaken. I'm not sure if this can work in Safari extensions. It have message passing API as well. It's different but but you can communicate with global page. You have access to window object from CS. So probably you can also attach onmessage event and use it in same way. Try it and let me know (under ubuntu I can't check...)

Comment: Tested your recommended flow: web app --window.postMessage--> CS --Safari-API--> global-Page. Works.